# How to find numbers of specific format and filter out certain range of values?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

How can I find numbers in format `0.xzy` where xzy are numbers and where x is `8-9` and write 5 lines before each match (including) to the `outputfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Find numbers in format `0.xzy` (`xzy` are numbers)

```
grep "^0.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" file
```

Find cases where x is 8-9

```
grep "^0.[89][0-9][0-9]$" file
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` to avoid overmatching and the OP doesn't state whole line matching. Also the `-[ABC]` flags are used for context matching.

Comment: MMmm sounds interesting. So would `grep ^0\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]$` work?

Comment: Now you won't match `01234` which is better but you also won't match `x: 0.923` because of the anchors `^`,`$`.

Comment: Well, I used these anchors because I get from the question that this is the only text in the line, so it has to start with 0 and end with [0-9]...

Answer (score 0):

To find numbers in the format `0.xzy` *(using word boundaries not forcing whole line match)* and print the 5 line preceding the match `-B5` and redirect the output to `outfile`:

```bsh
$ grep -B5 -Ew '0\.[0-9]{3}' file > outfile

# fix x to 8 or 9
$ grep -B5 -Ew '0\.[8-9][0-9]{2}' file > outfile
```

Note: the `.` needs escaping to mean a literal period otherwise `01234` will match. You will find `man grep` very helpful!